# Determine sample size and mean variance

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, sampling, mean, inference

Currently my data looks like this; there're 50 videos, and each video has been viewed and rated by 30 people, and I want to find out **if I could have a smaller sample size (n<30) that gives similar estimates (within +-0.5 points)**. *I'm taking the estimates when n=30 as a "population mean/standard deviation", and I want to see if a smaller sample size would get a similar results (determine sample size).

`VideoID  Score`
`1        3`  
`1        3`  
`1        2`  
`....    ...`  
`50       3`  
`50       4`

The distribution of scores (1-5) is a "skewed right" distribution, and the variation in scores within each video is different depending on the videos. I have tried randomly picking rows in this data frame, calculating standard deviation of scores in a for loop (re-sampling 50 times) and plotting it out. It seems like n=20 looks like a good choice, but I've no idea whether this method is logically flawed or not. What's the right way to accomplish my goal? Is there any hypothesized tests I should take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, as you said it is a true random sample from the population. 
But, I think that probably you're looking for something like [Z-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test#Example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm taking the estimates when n=30 as a "population mean/standard deviation", and I want to see if a smaller sample size would get a similar results (determine sample size).